# Oversize div moved when highlighted

Tags: css, html

I have a div that is sized by placing left:260px to make it stay to the right of the menu bar, as seen in Before. but once the user try to highlight something, it went to the right with 260px extra. It is sized for responsiveness so I use 100% but can't get a right percentage to prevent that from happened. Any idea how can I fix that? Preferably CSS directly, not calc or jquery. thanks

[image: After]

[image: Before]

Comment: if you have a try this please provide jsfiddle

Comment: left:260px to make it stay 'right'? why not right:somethingPX ?

Comment: share you fiddle link..